# Polynomials' multiplicative inverse

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $A(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Is there always a polynomial $B(x)$ for which

$$A(x)\cdot B(x)\equiv 1\pmod n$$

(for a given integer $n$). If the answer isn't yes, an answer "yes if $n$ is ____ (fill in with a characteristic the number has to have" would be interesting as well. Of course, no is also an answer.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300343/when-does-a-polynomial-in-gf-have-a-multiplicative-inverse) is on the track of what I'm interested in, it just doesn't have the key ingredient, the mod (that's why it turned out trivial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take $A(x)=xp(x)$, then naturally no such $B$ exists for any $n>1$.

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ were a prime, then the answer is "no" (unless $A(x)$ is a non zero constant), because the residue classes modulo a prime form a field, and the argument in an answer to the linked question covers that case. A consequence of this is that for $A(x)$ to have an inverse it is necessary that $A(x)$ is a non-zero constant modulo all the prime factors of $n$. This is actually also sufficient.
To cut a longish story short:

1. Chinese remainder theorem.
2. In a commutative ring elements of the form $u+y$, with $u$ a unit and $y$ nilpotent, are always invertible. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/466434/11619) for examples in the case $n=4$.