# Multiplicative polinomial inverse revisited

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

As it usually goes with asking questions for a third person... You don't get it right the first time.

Question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472947/polynomials-multiplicative-inverse) is as follows:

> Let $A(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Is there always
>   a polynomial $B(x)$ for which
>
> $$A(x)\cdot B(x)\equiv 1\pmod n$$
>
> (for a given integer $n$). If the answer isn't yes, an answer "yes if
>   $n$ is ____ (fill in with a characteristic the number has to have"
>   would be interesting as well. Of course, no is also an answer.
>
> [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300343/when-does-a-polynomial-in-gf-have-a-multiplicative-inverse) is on the track of what I'm interested in, it just
>   doesn't have the key ingredient, the mod (that's why it turned out
>   trivial).

The real *asker* of the question forgot to mention the master key ingredient to me, though. Multiplication in that congruence is not the ordinary one. It is done on $\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{R})/(x^N-1)$, so it should read

$$A(x)\cdot B(x) \text{ mod } (x^N-1) \text{ mod } n = 1$$

in a bit abused mod notation. I didn't edit the original question, since people already gave the correct answer to that question as it was stated. So, the question is still open - is there a $B$ for every $A$, now in this manner of multiplication?

Comment: Ahh! I see. This is a more interesting variant :-)

Comment: What's $\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{R})$ in this case?

Comment: Gotta be $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, @Loki.

Answer (score 1):

If $n=4$ and all the coefficients of $A(x)$ are even, then all the coefficients of $A(x)\cdot B(x)$ will be even, hence not 1 modulo $n$.

This remains true if the coefficients of $A(x)$ have any common factor, that divides $n$.

Answer (score 1):

A necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of such a polynomial $B(x)$ is the following: For each prime divisor $p\mid n$ we must have the condition that in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ we have $\gcd(\overline{A}(x),x^N-1)=1$. Here the notation $\overline{A}(x)$ means the polynomial $A(x)$ with all its coefficient projected down to the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (that you may also call reduction modulo $p$). Because $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field, this g.c.d. can be computed using the usual Euclidean algorithm of polynomial rings.

The necessity of this condition is clear. If for some $p\mid N$ we have that 
$\gcd(\overline{A}(x),x^N-1)=d(x)$ for some polynomial $d(x)$ that is not a constant, then that same factor $d(x)$ will be a factor modulo $p$ of $A(x)B(x)$ even if you subtract a multiple of $x^N-1$ (Gosh, it would be so much easier and clearer to say this in the language of quotient rings). So $A(x)B(x)$ reduced modulo $p$ and $x^N-1$ will be a non-constant. A fortiori the same will hold, if we only reduce it modulo $n$.

The sufficiency is a bit trickier, and depends on an easy version of Hensel lifting and the Chinese Remainder Theorem. If you want I can try and elaborate

Comment: Now I (or we, to be precise) would like to know how to find $B(x)$, if it exists?